# not found: value restrict deadbolt play framework

Tags: java, scala, web, playframework-2.0, deadbolt-2

Im using play 2.6.5 and deadbolt 2.6.1 java.

I am trying to add @restrict() {} but does not work.

im add the import

@import be.objectify.deadbolt.java.views.html.di.{restrict}

but all time say me

Compilation error
not found: value restrict

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.